# Using panTo and panBy simultaneously

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I would like to create a map with some pins on it (using leaflet). When the user clicks on one of them, the map should move until the pin is at the bottom of the map in the horizontal center.

My map is 400 pixels hight, so I'm using this code:

```
map.panTo(new L.LatLng(lat, lng));
map.panBy(new L.Point(0, -200));
```

It's working like a charm - only the IE has some problems with it: It starts to move towards the center of the map (`panTo`), but as soon as it stats to move towards the bottom as well (`panBy`) it stops to perform the moving towards the center.

How can I combine these two movements? I can't wait until `panTo` has centered the map, because this would cause the map to jump up and down if the pin is in the lower half of the map.

Comment: Adjust the lat/lng value to include the translation? This might be overcomplicated though; you'd have to calculate the resultant value based on the current zoom setting of the widget.

Comment: This sounds very complicated to me. Do you know a page with an example?

Comment: From the leaflet docs, you can get the lat/long point as pixels using: `latLngToPoint( <LatLng> latlng, <Number> zoom )` modify that, then convert it back to lat/long with: `pointToLatLng( <Point> point, <Number> zoom )` source: http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/reference.html#icrs

Comment: Shmiddty, this was the solution! Could you please write your hint as an answer? I would like to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the leaflet docs, you can get the lat/long point as pixels using:

`latLngToPoint( <LatLng> latlng, <Number> zoom )`

modify that, then convert it back to lat/long with:

`pointToLatLng( <Point> point, <Number> zoom )`

source: http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/reference.html#icrs

Comment: The functions are accessible through `map.options.crs` (`map = L.map('map')`)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use these two functions, that you can call directly on your map object:

```
// get your coordinates from marker or map.getCenter() or something else
let pixelPosition = map.latLngToLayerPoint(coord);
// edit pixel coordinates in pixelPosition object
let latLng = map.layerPointToLatLng(point);
map.setView(latLng);
```